# I am creating a new log level in python, but I am getting error "Failed to log following message properly:"

Tags: logging, python-3.7

I am trying to create a custom logger, where i want to print all the console level messages on stdout. and for remaining i dont want to give any handler in logging.

So i created a console level,

`CONSOLE = 60 def console(msg, *args, **kwargs): if logging.getLogger().isEnabledFor(CONSOLE): logging.log(CONSOLE, msg, args, **kwargs)`

`logging.Logger.console = console`

To get a logger which just prints console level log on stdout, I m using something like below code-

`
logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s",level=logging.INFO, datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

```
    streamhandler = logging.StreamHandler()

    streamhandler.setLevel(CONSOLE)

    logging.getLogger('').addHandler(streamhandler)

    logger = logging.getLogger("ABC")

    logging.Logger.console = console`
```

but my error is -

`22:46:55.280   ERROR   Failed to log following message properly: This is my message     22:46:55.280    DEBUG   TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 369, in getMessage msg = msg % self.args`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to update args to *args in my console method -

```
def console(msg, *args, **kwargs): 
   if logging.getLogger().isEnabledFor(CONSOLE): 
      logging.log(CONSOLE, msg, *args, **kwargs)
```